# How to list Apply Pay as a payment option in Schema.org?

Tags: html, semantic-web, schema.org, applepay

https://schema.org/PaymentMethod

> A payment method is a standardized procedure for transferring the monetary amount for a purchase. Payment methods are characterized by the legal and technical structures used, and by the organization or group carrying out the transaction.

It's [mentioned on Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/offering-apple-pay/):

> **Inform search engines that Apple Pay is accepted on your website.** If your website uses semantic markup to provide product details to search engines, list Apple Pay as a payment option.

I'm wondering how to list Apple Pay in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no standard way to add ApplePay markup as per [schema.org](https://schema.org/PaymentMethod) documentation.
However, the values mentioned there are *recommended*. And you can try adding your own value (and replace it later when the standard value is available).
Just note it should be an *url*.

I've tested the Google's [Rich Results Test tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) and custom ApplePay value passes the test successfully.